# How do I expose a field with a generic class to the Inspector?

Tags: unity, c#

I have some utilities implemented as generic classes.

I would like to have fields of these types exposed to the inspector but they appear to not display.

This test code:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestGenericClass<T>
{
    public string testField;

    public TestGenericClass(T testValue)
    {
        testField = testValue.ToString();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class TestNormalClass
{
    public string testField;

    public TestNormalClass(string testValue)
    {
        testField = testValue;
    }
}

public class MonoBehaviourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TestGenericClass<string> testGenericClass = new TestGenericClass<string>("generic");
    public TestNormalClass testNormalClass = new TestNormalClass("normal");
}
```

Produces this result:

[image]

As you can see the field for the generic class is missing.

How can I expose a field with a generic class to the inspector?

Answer (score 3):

I think there are several people who have come across this problem before. The short of it is that there isn't a way to directly serialise the class. However, there are a few workarounds posted in solutions in the unity answers:

[here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/214300/serializable-class-using-generics.html) using subclasses:

```
 [Serializable]
 public class GenericClassOfString : GenericClass<String>
 {
 }

 [Serializable]
 public class SomeClass
 {
    public GenericClassOfString stringClassField; //serializes
 }
```

and [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/783456/solution-how-to-serialize-interfaces-generics-auto.html) using inheritance/interfaces:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityObject = UnityEngine.Object;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Assets.Vexe.ShowEmAll
{
    public abstract class SerializedBehaviour : MonoBehaviour, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private StrObjDict serializedObjects = new StrObjDict(); // a serializable Dictionary<string, UnityObject>
        [SerializeField]
        private StrStrDict serializedStrings = new StrStrDict(); // a serializable Dictionary<string, string>

        private BinaryFormatter mSerializer;

        private BinaryFormatter serializer
        {
            get
            {
                if (mSerializer == null)
                {
                    mSerializer = new BinaryFormatter();
                    var selector = new SurrogateSelector();

                    Action<Type, ISerializationSurrogate> addSurrogate = (type, surrogate) =>
                        selector.AddSurrogate(type, new StreamingContext(), surrogate);

                    addSurrogate(typeof(Vector3), new Vector3Surrogate());
                    // add more custom surrogates here

                    // create our unity surrogate
                    var unitySurrogate = new AnotherUnityObjectSurrogate(serializedObjects);

                    // get all unity object types
                    var unityTypes = typeof(UnityObject).Assembly.GetTypes()
                                                        .Where(t => typeof(UnityObject).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                                                        .ToArray();

                    // add our surrogate to let the serializer use it to handle unity objects serialization
                    foreach (var t in unityTypes)
                        addSurrogate(t, unitySurrogate);

                    serializer.SurrogateSelector = selector;
                }
                return mSerializer;
            }
        }

        public void OnAfterDeserialize()
        {
            Deserialize();
        }

        public void OnBeforeSerialize()
        {
            Serialize();
        }

        private void Serialize()
        {
            foreach (var field in GetInterfaces())
            {
                var value = field.GetValue(this);
                if (value == null)
                    continue;

                string name = field.Name;
                var obj = value as UnityObject;
                if (obj != null) // the implementor is a UnityEngine.Object
                {
                    serializedObjects[name] = obj; // using the field's name as a key because you can't have two fields with the same name
                }
                else
                {
                    // try to serialize the interface and store the result in our other dictionary
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(stream, value);
                        stream.Flush();
                        serializedObjects.Remove(name); // it could happen that the field might end up in both the dictionaries, ex when you change the implementation of the interface to use a System.Object instead of a UnityObject
                        serializedStrings[name] = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Deserialize()
        {
            foreach (var field in GetInterfaces())
            {
                object result = null;
                string name = field.Name;

                // Try fetch member serialized value
                UnityObject obj;
                if (serializedObjects.TryGetValue(name, out obj)) // if the implementor is a UnityObject, then we just fetch the value from our dictionary as the result
                {
                    result = obj;
                }
                else // otherwise, get it from our other dictionary
                {
                    string serializedString;
                    if (serializedStrings.TryGetValue(name, out serializedString))
                    {
                        // deserialize the string back to the original object
                        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(serializedString);
                        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                            result = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    }
                }

                field.SetValue(this, result);
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetInterfaces()
        {
            return GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                            .Where(f => !f.IsDefined(typeof(HideInInspector)) && (f.IsPublic || f.IsDefined(typeof(SerializeField))))
                            .Where(f => f.FieldType.IsInterface);
        }
    }

    public interface ITestInterface
    {
        string StringValue { get; set; }
        float FloatValue { get; set; }
        Vector3 Vector3Value { get; set; }
        Transform Target { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SystemImplementer : ITestInterface
    {
        public string StringValue { get; set; }
        public float FloatValue { get; set; }
        public Vector3 Vector3Value { get; set; }
        public Transform Target { get; set; }
    }

    // This should have its own file
    public class UnityImplementer : MonoBehaviour, ITestInterface
    {
        public string StringValue { get; set; }
        public float FloatValue { get; set; }
        public Vector3 Vector3Value { get; set; }
        public Transform Target { get; set; }
    }

    // Put this in a file on its own inside an "Editor" folder
    [CustomEditor(typeof(SerializationTest))]
    public class SerializationTestEditor : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            base.OnInspectorGUI();

            var typedTarget = target as SerializationTest;
            if (GUILayout.Button("Set to system implementor"))
                typedTarget.test = new SystemImplementer();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Set to unity implementor"))
                typedTarget.test = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType<UnityImplementer>() ?? new GameObject().AddComponent<UnityImplementer>();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Print value"))
                Debug.Log(typedTarget.test);
        }
    }
}
```